# How to refer to another field computed in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Consider a simplified example:

```
SELECT
  lengthy_expression AS a,
  g(a) AS b,
  h(a) AS c,
  ...
FROM
  my_table
```

Here, `lengthy_expression` represents a complex expression that uses several fields from `my_table` and spans several lines. Its result is used to calculate two other fields `b` and `c`. However, the above is not allowed in standard SQL, because an expression in the `WHERE` clause is not allowed to refer to the result of another expression in the `WHERE` clause (why not is beyond me).

The naive option is to repeat the `lengthy_expression`, but that's what I explicitly want to avoid.

One option is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT
  a,
  g(a) AS b,
  h(a) AS c,
  ...
FROM (
  SELECT
    lengthy_expression AS a,
    ...
  FROM
    my_table
)
```

But as you can see, I now need to repeat the other fields `...` that the outer query needs.

Maybe a subquery with a join then?

```
SELECT
  a,
  g(a) AS b,
  h(a) AS c,
  ...
FROM
  my_table
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    lengthy_expression AS a
  FROM
    my_table
) USING id
```

It works, but now there's a (possibly expensive) join that serves no purpose except to keep the query readable. And it doesn't even serve that purpose very well, because the `lengthy_expression` is tucked away below the point where it's used, and the human reader has to jump all over the place to find out what's going on.

An alternative is using a CTE:

```
WITH
my_table_with_a AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    lengthy_expression AS a
  FROM
    my_table
)
SELECT
  *,
  g(a) AS b,
  h(a) AS c,
  ...
FROM
  my_table_with_a
```

At least now the reading order more or less matches the logical order in which operations happen, but it's pretty verbose, and finding a good name for `my_table_with_a` is difficult. Especially because in practice, I'm repeating this pattern two or three times.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would use CTEs.  You say they are verbose, but new lines of code are relatively 'cheap' compared to complex/repeated joins.  If a coworker (or you in 6 months) needs to review your code, CTEs are very readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a,
  g(a) AS b,
  h(a) AS c,
FROM `project.dataset.my_table`,
UNNEST([lengthy_expression]) a
```

Below is extremely simplified example of above approach

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 x, 2 y, 3 z UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5, 6
)
SELECT 
  a,
  a / 2 AS b,
  2 * a AS c
FROM `project.dataset.my_table`,
UNNEST([x + y + z]) a   
WHERE a > 10
```

with result

```
Row a   b   c    
1   15  7.5 30
```

Note: in case if result of `lengthy_expression` is an ARRAY by itself - you need to enclose it into struct as array of array is not supported in BigQuery

Comment: Hah, that's a very interesting hack, thank you! Any idea if this has better/worse performance than the subquery or CTE approach?

Comment: I don't expect any performance hit here - but obviously less verbose and easier to maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Just use `*`:

```
SELECT a, g(a) AS b, h(a) AS c, ...
FROM (SELECT lengthy_expression AS a, t.*
      ...
      FROM my_table t
     ) t
```

I'm pretty sure BigQuery won't charge you for the fields that are not actually used by the query.

Comment: That's true, even with CTEs, unused fields get optimized away. Still, I find this style fairly unreadable, especially when you start nesting them (`d` depends on `c` depends on `b` depends on `a`).

Comment: @Thomas . . . This does what you want.  I'm not sure what you are referring to as "unreadable".  Not reusing column aliases solves two problems:  (1) it removes ambiguity when an alias and column have the same name; (2) it makes it possible for the column expressions to be evaluated independently (i.e. there is no order of evaluation in a `select`.